# C# getting a line from appSetting?

Tags: c#, xml

Is there an easier way of doing the lines below?

```
var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("../../../MyWebSite/Web.config");
var mysqlconn = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode(
    "//appSettings//add[@key='mysqlconn']").Attributes["value"].Value;
```

Answer (score 11):

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mysqlconn"]
```

Should give you the value. You may want to move them into a `<connectionStrings />` section, which you can use:

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mysqlconn"]
                                                                .ConnectionString
```

Comment: Don't forget u will need to add a reference to 'System.Configuration'.

Comment: This is an XML of my other app. How do I load it into ConfigurationManager?